# Sqlite query formulation targeting row content

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to formulate the right query to select records that each have a category:

```
drop table if exists entries;
create table entries (
id integer primary key autoincrement,
title string not null,
text string not null,
pub_date integer,
category string not null);
```

I read the sqlite documentation and I still can't figure out why I get :"no such column:Music" Where music is the dummy category.

```
Here's the function:

@app.route('/<category_name>')
def show_entries(category_name):
cur = g.db.execute('select id,title, text,pub_date,category from entries where category   
 =' +category_name)       
entries = [dict(id=row[0], title=row[1], text=row[2],
           pub_date=row[3],category=row[4]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code but the most basic one is that your final SQL statement does not place quotation marks around the value of category_name as required for strings in SQL (and most other languages).

What you are sending to SQLite is:

```
select id,title, text,pub_date,category from entries where category = music
```

and it should be:

```
select id,title, text,pub_date,category from entries where category = 'music'
```

However, you should never build SQL statements by concatenating strings together since that exposes you to the possibility that a sneaky person (or 'bot) put something into one of those strings that will destroy your database.

Instead, you should do this:

```
 cur = g.db.execute(
         'select id,title, text,pub_date,category from entries where category = ?',
         [category_name])
```

which is called a *parameterized query*.  In this case, the database will make sure that category_name is handled properly as a piece of string data rather than (potentially) part of the SQL statement.

Comment: thanks, it worked! As you said, I knew what sqlite was understanding as the query and I tried putting quotes but not as a parameterized query. That's the thing,sometimes when something doesn't work,I tell myself that I will care about security afterwards. I remember reading about this but I thought it wouldn't influence the query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a quoting problem.  The category value needs double quotes around it or else it gets interpreted as a field name.

Try this:

```
cur = g.db.execute('select id,title, text,pub_date,category from entries where category = (?)', (category_name,))
```

Comment: you're putting a comma at the end because it's a tuple? and he's using a list(other answer).

Comment: Yes, it's a tuple. There's no need to use a list here, since you are not going to modify the parameter once passed to the `execute` method. The relevant [example in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) uses a tuple, too.

Comment: I saw that too.The python documentation is really good.I m getting the feel of Python and I really like it.I mean as a first language to learn. I remember using Turtle in school when I was 12.I didn t know it was Python then.In 1992,is that possible?